Time of collision of two particles arriving with Planck time difference
Suppose two particles, $A$ and $B$, arrive at a certain point $P$. After arriving, whichever particle arrives first stops until the other particle arrives later and collides with it.
Now, let's say that the absolute value of the difference between the particles' arrival times ($t_A$ and $t_B$, respectively) is less than Planck time $t_p$:
$|t_A-t_B|<t_p$
In this case, at what time will the actual interaction happen?
In the classical physics world it will be naturally $max(t_A, t_B)$, but can we state the same when talking about Planck scale?

Why does the Planck time matter here? It is derived from combining various constants, but has no particularly good physical meaning.

This scenario seems rather vague to me. Why does the first particle stop? How does it stop? Does it collide with something else that you didn't mention? Does it come to a stop instantly, or does it decelerate gradually? Etc.

@PM2Ring why does it matter?

@JonCuster so the answer is max(tA,tB)?

How are the particles interacting in the first place?

Interactions between particles take place over a time span, in a volume of space. You're specifying the time of the collision to Planck scale precision, but the locations and velocities are not similarly precise.

I think the whole notion of a "particle" breaks down well before you get to the Planck scale. At high energies / small distances you have to use field theory to model interactions.

@EricSmith I think the question is due to the fact that it's commonly cited that spacetime might become discontinuous at the Planck scale, leading to an intuition that there "aren't" timescales shorter than that. Agreed, you wouldn't use regular physics at that scale, you'd use a field theory description of the system.

That spacetime "might" become discontinuous at the Planck scale is speculative in the extreme. As far as I am aware there is no evidence in favor of discrete spacetime, and some (limited) experimental evidence against it.
